# 箇条書きなどの書き方のフォーマット

Tags: untagged

リストや箇条書きのフォーマットは一括で決まっているのでしょうか？
また、名称はあるのでしょうか？検索しようとしてもうまく一覧のようなものがヒットしませんでした。

リストだったら、文頭に1.
箇条書きなら、-
など、このHP特有のものだと思っていたら他のサイトでも同じ記号が扱われていました。

その他スニペットや、色を変えるなど、いろいろ使いこなしたいので、
もしルールがあるなら勉強したいと思い、質問致しました。
よろしくお願い致します。

追記：
スタックオーバーフローに限らず全てのページで使えるものに関しての質問でした。

Comment: このサイトのことを質問していますか？基本的にMarkdown記法です。そして、ここではなくMeta質問にすべきかと。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Markdown](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)と呼ばれるテキストの記法です。プレーンテキストのままでも読める上で、ツールによる自動変換も想定されています。
ある程度の類似性はありますが、細かくは環境毎に異なるフォーマットを採用しているのが実情です。ですので、ここStack Overflowの書式が他すべてに通用するわけではありません。